# Optimizing nested loops over dictionaries

Tags: python, loops, optimization, dictionary

I have 3 dictionaries: `queries_dict`, `actions_dict`, `results_dict`, `800k`,`700K`, and `7M` keys respectively. To find which actions related to which result, I have to use `queries_dict`. I'd like to optimize the following nested loops:

```
for q_id, q in queries_dict.iteritems():
    for ac_id, ac in ((ac_id, ac) for (ac_id, ac) in actions_dict.iteritems() if ac.query_id == q.query_id and q.session_id == ac.session_id):
        for r in q.results:
            if r.rank_of_result == ac.rank_of_result:
                results_dict[r.result_id].actions.append(ac)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [*Dictionary view objects*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html) like `viewitems()` that thread as `sets` and as sets has O(1) for checking the membership.(But its possible just when your values are hashable!!)

> If all values are hashable, so that (key, value) pairs are unique and hashable, then the items view is also set-like.